# p-adic valuation

Tags: p-adic-number-theory

My question is two-fold. First off, let's define $v_p$ to be the valuation on $\mathbb{Q}$ defines by setting $v_p( \frac{a}{b} p^n)=n$, where $(a,p)=(b,p)=1$. How exactly does $v_p$ extend to $\mathbb{Q}_p$ (if it all)? Is this hard to show?

Secondly, let $\alpha \in \mathbb{Q}_p$ be non-zero. I was wondering how difficult it would be to understand the values of $|1+\alpha^2|_p$. We have $$|1+\alpha^2|_p\leq \max( 1, |\alpha|_p^2).$$ Is there anything more interesting that can be said?

Comment: I may be not understanding something, but how did you arrive to $\;\Bbb Q_p\;$ if not via the $\;p\,-$ adic valuation $\;v_p\;$ on the rationals?

Comment: I was about to answer your question, but I don’t know what your definition of $\Bbb Q_p$ is. What are $p$-adic numbers, for you? Do you think of them as infinite series of the shape $\sum_ia_ip^i$, where the $a$’s are from the set $\{0,1,\dots,p-1\}$? If so, the $v$ you want is gotten by telling the lowest value of $n$ with $a_n\ne0$. But there are other ways of thinking of $p$-adic numbers, and maybe you’re using one of those?

Comment: Yes, I'm thinking of $\mathbb{Q}_p$ as infinite series $\sum_{i\geq k}a_ip^i$ with $a_i\in \{0, 1, \ldots, p-1\}$.

Answer (score 1):

With the definition of $p$-adic numbers as (potentially) infinite series $z=\sum_{n=N_0}^\infty a_np^n$ with each coefficient $a_n\in\{0,1,\cdots,p-1\}$, then $v(z)$ is the smallest $n$ with $a_n\ne0$. This value may be negative, but if nonnegative, we say that $z\in\Bbb Z_p$.

The valuation-behavior of the polynomial $1+z^2$ is only somewhat interesting, in that if $v(z)>0$, then $v(1+z^2)=0$, as you know. What is rather more interesting is to compare the valuation of $f(z)$ with the valuation of $z$ when $f$ is a polynomial (or even a power series) with no constant term. And this question is yet more interesting when you look at possibilities for $z$ that lie in algebraic field extensions of $\Bbb Q_p$. For then, if you keep the convention that $v(p)=1$, you’ll have all rational numbers being possibilities for $v(z)$. Then the “valuation function” of $f$ will be a concave function (concave downward) whose graph is polygonal. This valuation function is closely related to the Newton Polygon of $f$, which also is defined by means of the “additive” valuation $v$ rather than the (multiplicative) absolute value, which many people find more intuitive.

Comment: Thanks, this is the type of thing I'm trying to learn about. Let $f(x)$ be some polynomial in $\mathbb{Q}_p[x]$ with no constant term. If I understand correctly, there is a way to compare $v( f(x))$ with $v(x)$. How complicated is it to compare the two valuations ? Anyway, one can also take $f(x)\in K_p[x]$, where $K_p$ is an algebraic extension of $\mathbb{Q}_p$ and do the same thing: compare $v(f(x))$ with $v(x)$. However, I'm a little hazy on how one would extend the valuation $v$ on $\mathbb{Q}_p$ to an extension $K_p$. How is this done?

Comment: If you want to e-mail me, I’ll be happy to fill you in on a bunch of these things, but I think it better if you use a strong (but not impossible) text like Gouvêa. My general recommendation to you is: do lots of hand computations.